# How to replace text partially in linux using sed

Tags: awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I have an XML tag that I need to manipulate on Linux:

```
<m1:PayloadId>TESTCASE01_0000123456</m1:PayloadId>
```

I need to change the text from `TESTCASE01_0000123456` to `TESTCASE01_1234567890` between the tags.

I used this sed command in my code:

```
sed -i 's/PayloadId>.*</m1:PayloadId>'0000123456'</g' t1.xml
```

but it replaces the entire text. I need to retain `TESTCASE01_`.

Comment: It is always advisable to parse xml with tools who know xml parsing, like xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed  's|\(<m1:PayloadId>TESTCASE01\)_0000123456\(</m1:PayloadId>\)|\1_1234567890\2|g' t1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(<m1:PayloadId>[^>_]*_\)[^<]*/\11234567890/' file
```

Match on the opening tag and the value that follows and save the tag and its value upto and including the first `_` in back reference `\1`. Then replace the match by the back reference and the required numeric suffix.